# Is it possible to reinitialize static mutable fields in a class?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-class-loaders

I'm trying to automate the testing process for customly written programs designed to solve competitive programming challenges. Below is a dummy sample implementation of Solution:

```
public class Solution {
    private static String dummyField = "initial";


    public static int initialize(InputStream in) {
        //competitive programmer custom code
        System.out.println(dummyField);
        dummyField = "changed";
        return subCaseCount;
    }

    public void processSingleSubCase(InputStream in) {
        //competitive programmer custom code
    }
}
```

Prewritten test code for solution regardless of its implementation:

```
public void testSolution() throws FileNotFoundException {
        for(File testResource : testResources) {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(testResource);
            int subCaseCount = Foo.initialize(in);
            for (int subCase = 0; subCase < subCaseCount; subCase++) {
                new Foo().processSingleSubCase(in);
            }

            //magic call to re-init all static fields without knowing their number/names in advance goes here
        }

        //console current output:
        //initial
        //changed
        //changed
        //...

        //desired:
        //initial
        //initial
        //initial
        //....
}
```

The static fields can be mutable, so caching the initial values and mapping them to field names using reflection as a first setup, then reassigning them in between iterations won't do.

I did manage to come up with a working solution which basically reloads the class using a different class loader in between iterations, it did work but was slow: it took about **50 seconds** just to reload classes 300 times (test resources are auto generated and I'd like to have the flexibility to auto generate as many as tolerable).

Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind is: Don't use statics. The second idea is: Prior to the first test, cache the static values, then reassign them from the cache between tests.

Comment: I know static is not recommended in general, but for competitive programming challenges it is very tempting to use them especially for problems with multiple test cases per input. Sometimes the only alternative to static is to create an additional inner class to hold global state across sub test cases, which compared to static would be overkill. The general solution format of competitive programming challenges is a  single self contained class so static shouldn't be evil. That said as I mentioned in my post caching static values won't do, since the values can be mutable.

Comment: I didn't say static was evil, I just proposed a solution (not using it). I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean about caching not being sufficient. If you mean the values may be references to mutable objects, then of course the cache would need to have deep copies. That's not a problem, surely?

Comment: Oh wow, don't know why I didn't think of deep copying. Make your comment an answer if you'd like, I'll accept it. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can't re-initialize a variable because initialization is something that happens upon initial declaration, as the word indicates. You can reassign it, though.

Comment: "I know static is not recommended in general, but for competitive programming challenges it is very tempting to use them" - "I know armed robbery is illegal, but for quick cash it's very tempting". It's at least as fast to do the right thing as it is the wrong thing, up front. If you want the code to actually _work_ and not cost hours or days searching on SO and elsewhere for answers to why it doesn't while fending off angry users, the right thing is waaay faster.

Comment: You don't get it... I have control over the prewritten test code, but not my users custom implementation of Solution. I just can't guarantee my users won't use static, it's a feature in the language and preventing them from using it just to get pre-written tests to work is simply not right. armed robbery? oh my...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two thoughts for how to do this are:

1. Use instances rather than `static`s, since that way the new instance for each test is fresh.
2. If you need (or want) to stick with `static`s: Prior to the first test, cache the `static` values, then reassign them from the cache between tests. If the `static` values are object references referring to mutable objects, you'll need to make deep copies.